# How reduce width of showMaterialModalBottomSheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

i used showMaterialModalBottomSheet want to reduce the width, not full-screen width

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              ),
              useRootNavigator: true,
              enableDrag: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      height: 300,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text("Testing"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.anchorLock),
        ),
```

what want to design like this

[[image]][1]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] your question and copy-paste it into the question itself in between \`\`\` the code \`\`\`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show bottom sheet method has a constraints property which can be used to reduce the width. Add this to showBottomSheet method

```dart
constraints: BoxConstraints(
   maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-50,              
),
```